# IE: Cam is not getting turn off after taking the photo

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, webcam

I'm working on an application, in which there is photo capture option. We are using Scriptcam API (http://www.scriptcam.com/docs.cfm) for developing this usecase.

This is working fine in Firefox, Chrome. But problematic only in IE. I can see camera on indicator still, even if I close the application.

The camera should turn off in 2 scenarios:
1) Once the photo is taken
2) When we click on Cross mark on photocapture view, along with the view, camera has to be turned off.

I have gone through the below link, but I couldn't find any answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980405/how-to-get-webcam-light-to-turn-off-after-video-recording-is-complete-in-ie#new-answer?newreg=604f3e1bd67449bcb52135a04b2707ac
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You may try asking their support team.

Comment: We are testing script-cam plug-in in our application. They provide technical support only for commercial users. Soon we gonna buy this license. @AlokSwain

Comment: Can anyone please provide solution for this? We don't have this license at to get support from vendor team.